# Enabling virtualization in BIOS causes Windows to stuck while booting

Tags: windows, boot, bios, virtualization, windows-8.1

I installed **Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Phone** and at the end it popped up that **Hyper-V** (virtualization tool used in Windows Phone Emulator) isn't available on my computer. I done some research and I read that in order to use Hyper-V, I need to enable virtualization in BIOS. And that's what I did, but then, my Windows 8.1 Pro got stuck while booting and just keeps spinning the circle under the Windows logo. So I went to BIOS and disabled virtualization. Then my PC booted like always. If anyone needs further details or so, just ask.

Device used to this is **HP Pavilion dm1-4310sw** laptop. On HP site there is no BIOS updates for me. I'm not able to boot in safe mode with virtualization enabled.

Comment: Are you able to boot into safe mode with visualization enabled?  Specific information about your hardware will be required.  Update your question with this information.

Comment: Search for your PC's make and model number or BIOS brand and revision and "Hyper-V" - you may need to flash the BIOS or a slew of other things.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after longer research I found out that this problem appears to happen with devices working with **Ralink RT3290** drivers. For everyone facing this problem (and having mentioned drivers obviously) the only thing to do is going to [this site](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?cc=US&lang=en&swItem=vc_121172_1&ac.admitted=1395450849380.876444892.199480143) and installing the drivers. Then just reboot, go to the BIOS, enable virtualization. It should work perfect.